# What is causing the Stack Buffer Overflow?

Tags: arrays, c++11, stl

I was solving this question on LeetCode - https://leetcode.com/problems/k-closest-points-to-origin/
I could make two things - 1) We needed to sort the distances of given points in ascending order.
2) We also had to have the point associated with that distance from origin.

After brainstorming, I came up with the idea of using maps from c++ stl. As they would take care of sorting and also the association of distance and point. My code is as follows -

```
class Solution 
{
public:
    vector<vector<int>> kClosest(vector<vector<int>>& points, int k) 
    {
        map<double,vector<int>> m;
        vector<vector<int>> answer;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
        {
            double x = sqrt((points[i][0] * points[i][0]) + (points[i][1] * points[i][1]));
            m.insert(pair<double, vector<int>>(x,{points[i][0], points[i][1]}));
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            auto it = m.begin();
            advance(it,i);
            answer.push_back(it->second);
        }
        
        return answer;
    }
};
```

It is working fine for the first 2 testcases and throwing runtime error - stack buffer overflow, I had initially used float for x but I thought because of constraints it was causing the error, so I changed the type to double but still no luck!

It would be a great help if someone can help me figure the mistake here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have the input that lead to the crash? Then run locally on your own system, and use a *debugger* to catch the crash and find out when and where in your code it happens.

Comment: **(1)** you access `points[i][0]` and `points[i][1]` without checking if these vectors are of the expected size, is that correct? **(2)** You do `advance(it, i)` with maximal value of `i` being `k-1`. Is there an assumption that `k == points.size()`? That would be weird, since vectors have size inside them anyway.

Comment: Aside: `m.emplace(x, points[i]);` is a much easier way of inserting into your map.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, I was just provided the last executed output.

Comment: @freakish 1) The vectors will be of the expected size as for i, I am iterating from 0 to the size of points and as we have two coordinates the second index has to be 0 and 1 only. 2) I wasn't sure how I could access the elements of map, after searching I found advance is a way, so yes there could be something wrong there as Imranur Rahman has pointed below.

Comment: @Caleth Again I am relatively new to this, so will take care in the future, thank you for the help.

Comment: That's a problem with so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites: They tend to not provide the input which makes it very hard to debug. It's not the *only* problem with such sites, but it's one that makes it hard to learn "proper" programming (debugging is an integral part of programming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think of a case where there are two points [-1, 0] and [0, 1], and the value of k is 2. If you use map, you will get only 1 <key, value> pair for your case, because the key (in this case sqrt(1)) is same for both points. So, you need to use **multimap**, where you can have the same key multiple times. Read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multimap-associative-containers-the-c-standard-template-library-stl/).

The working code example based on your code:

```
class Solution 
{
public:
    vector<vector<int>> kClosest(vector<vector<int>>& points, int k) 
    {
        multimap<int,vector<int>> m;
        vector<vector<int>> answer;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
        {
            int x = (points[i][0] * points[i][0]) + (points[i][1] * points[i][1]);
            m.insert(pair<int, vector<int>>(x,{points[i][0], points[i][1]}));
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end() && i < k; it++, i++) {
            //cout << it->first << " : " << it->second[0] << ", " << it->second[1] << endl;
            answer.push_back(it->second);
        }
        
        return answer;
    }
};
```

Suggestions:

- You don't need to bother about whether to store the distance value in double or float. Since you are comparing sqrt(some_value1) with sqrt(some_value2), you can omit the sqrt altogether.
- std::advance has a linear time complexity. You can just simply initialize the iterator at the beginning of the for loop, and increment with ++ operator. This operator has a constant time complexity. Read more about std::advance [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance).

Comment: Feel free to upvote if this solves your problem. Cheers!